# Getting ranking based on a number from CTE

Tags: postgresql

I have a complex situation in PostgreSQL 11 where i need to generate a numbering based on a single figure which i get it from a CTE.

Below is the CTE

```
 WITH pending_orders_to_be_processed_details
    AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY so.create_date ) as queue_no
, name,so.create_date ::TIMESTAMP
    FROM  picking sp
    LEFT JOIN order so ON so.name=sp.origin
    WHERE sp.state IN('assigned','confirmed')
     )
    ,orders_which_can_be_processed_today AS
    (
    -- This CTE will give me a count of orders 
and its hourly average, Lets say count is 400 and hourly avg is 3

    )
```

Now i need to number the details according to the hourly average, Means the first 3 orders need to be ranked as 1, next 3 to be ranked as 2 and so on, so that i can able to identify that these can be processed based on this ranking.

Input will be

```
name         queu_number.  create_date
    so1            1       2021-03-11 12:00:00
    so2            2       2021-03-11 13:00:00
    so3            3       2021-03-11 14:00:00
    so4            4       2021-03-11 15:00:00
    so5            5       2021-03-11 16:00:00
    so6            6       2021-03-11 17:00:00
    so7            7       2021-03-11 18:00:00
    so8            8       2021-03-11 19:00:00
    so9            9       2021-03-11 20:00:00
```

The expected output will be

```
name         rank
so1            1
so2            1
so3            1
so4            2
so5            2
so6            2
so7            3
so8            3
so9            3
```

Any help/suggestions.

Comment: @S-Man Changed my question and added input and output.If you can help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I recently learned about a function, which fits well here:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be5352a0c479b89904d64226f0d0b384)

You can use the [`ntile()` window function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-ntile-function/) for that:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ntile(3) OVER (ORDER BY create_date)
FROM mytable
```

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49b8fd8115ab98ae2351eaf5c559ee01)

Since you already created a cumulative row count, you can use this to create your expected rank:

```
SELECT
    *,
    floor((queue_no - 1) / 3) + 1 as rank
FROM my_cte
```

1. `queue_no - 1` (so, `1` to `3` will be shifted to `0` to `2`)
2. Diff by `3`: so, `0` to `2` will be `0.x` and `3` to `5` will be `1.x`, ...
3. Now round these result to `0`, `1`, `2`, ...
4. If you want to start with `1` instead of `0`, add `1`

Comment: Thanks a lot , Worked perfectly!

Comment: Added a better solution.